# NSRangeException index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

I am creating a react native app. I don't know what I did to cause this issue, but now it appears even if I comment out my entire app except for a single . Sometimes it randomly doesn't occur, but I have no way of eliminating it completely.

```
NSRangeException: * -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array
```

The only Array in my app is a pre-set array that is always full, so I don't think that can cause this issue. But this flatlist is the only place it's used.

```
import { FlatList, View, Text, TouchableHighlight } from "react-native";
import { useContext } from "react";
import Swipeable from "react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable";
import { arrData } from "../../data";
import { PlayingContext } from "../../app/_layout";
import ListItem from "../ListItem/index";
import SwipeButtons from "../SwipeButtons";
import MantraListStyles from "./MantraList.styles";

const { container, list } = MantraListStyles;
const MantraList = () => {
  const changeContext = useContext(PlayingContext).setPlaying;
  const handlePress = (newPlaying) => {
    changeContext(newPlaying);
  };

  return (
    <View style={container}>
      <FlatList
        data={arrData}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item?.id}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Swipeable renderRightActions={() => <SwipeButtons />}>
            <TouchableHighlight
              activeOpacity={0.85}
              underlayColor="darkgrey"
              onPress={() => handlePress(item)}
            >
              <ListItem fileData={item} />
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </Swipeable>
        )}
        style={list}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default MantraList;
```

Again, I have completely deleted this component in some cases, and the error continued to occur. I have commented out everything, and it continued to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning Xcode's derived data, clean the xcode project and run npm start --reset-cache in root folder of your react-native project